# Why is gdb not working in eclipse when it is working fine from command line?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have created and successfully compiled a C++ application for Linux using eclipse. When I debug it from the command line everything works perfect, I can debug just fine.

But I require debugging in eclipse because is more convenient and easy. I configure the debug session and when trying to launch it I get the error:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-run
Error message from debugger back end:
Warning:\nCannot insert breakpoint 1.\nCannot access memory at address 0x1fff82e8\nCannot insert breakpoint 2.\nCannot access memory at address 0x80001ea4\n
Warning:\nCannot insert breakpoint 1.\nCannot access memory at address 0x1fff82e8\nCannot insert breakpoint 2.\nCannot access memory at address 0x80001ea4\n
```

But I have no idea why I am getting that error, especially because gdb is working fine when I execute it from cmd.

These are my c++ compiler flags in eclipse:

```
-std=c++98 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

When creating the project I chose the "Hello world C++ Project" and the "Linux GCC" as the toolchain.

I'm working with the following versions of GDB and Eclipse:

- Eclipse Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
- GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1

Comment: Can you elaborate on the versions you are using, i.e. which GDB and Eclipse/CDT version in particular.

Comment: @JonahGraham that is a good suggestion. I edited the question to include this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can reproduce this problem is to have address breakpoints enabled. As far as I am concerned this is a bug in CDT, but in the meantime as a workaround remove or disable any address breakpoints from the *Breakpoints* view.

I have submitted [Bug 509894](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509894) to track the issue in CDT.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. It turns out that I had a couple of address breakpoints in the breakpoints view, (that I don't know how they got there), but just deleting them everything works fine now!