# Omnet++> Caused a Debugging error

Tags: gdb, omnet++

I was debugging on Omnet++ program and I was trying to find the value of a constant so I went around with the options in the debugger.

Then when I wanted to debug again I got this error

> Error in final launch sequence Failed to execute MI command:
>   -exec-run Error message from debugger back end:
>   Warning:\nCannot insert breakpoint 1.\nCannot access memory at address 0x0\n
>   Warning:\nCannot insert breakpoint 1.\nCannot access memory at address
>   0x0\n

The program runs fine but not with debugging

I searched online and found that this error has to do with GDB
accessing memory at address 0x0 means that I am trying to dereference a null pointer.

Also this error is shown in the debug tab of omnet++

> terminated, exit value: 0 gdb (7.11.1)

Any one have an idea what might be the problem. Should I remove the Omnet++ and download it again?

Comment: Where are you setting a breakpoint exactly? It sounds like you're trying to set a breakpoint at an invalid location.

Comment: Well first I had 2 breakpoints and I added two extra breakpoints at which the time I had error then I removed all of them and kept one that I am sure was working fine, still I am getting the same error.

`virtual void setVlanID(int vlanID);`
`this->vlanID = vlanID;`

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, this may be a dup of [Why is gdb not working in eclipse when it is working fine from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453034/why-is-gdb-not-working-in-eclipse-when-it-is-working-fine-from-command-line)

Comment: it is Eclipse based true, but different IDE

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but I found this line in the breakpoints tab as shown in the picture, solved by removing it.

[image: Omnet++ Debugger]